# How to emulate click event to cycle through slides with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c0stmbqg/2/

JQuery:

```
$(".slidelink").click(function() {
    var vSLinkID = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".slidelinkimg").css("display", "none");
    $(".slidecontent").css("display", "none");
    console.log(vSLinkID);
    $("#slide"+vSLinkID.slice(-2)).fadeIn("slow");
    $("#slidelinkimg"+vSLinkID.slice(-2)).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

The above Jquery fires every time a DIV with a `slidelink` is clicked it displays the corresponding DIV and images.

How can I have a function which does the click function, except it cycles from 1st slide to n-th slide and back to 1st slide and so forth with a delay until I click on a slide. When I click on a slide it should show the slide and then continue with the cycle from the next slide.

Comment: _I fixed it locally, and it is working awesome for me!_ How is your fiddle useful if it does not work? :)

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle? At least add all your code here.. It's hard to answer without seeing the code..

Comment: Ooooops sorry. I fixed it. Silly mistake. Fiddle is working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'd want to get a reference to slides that can be clicked. I recommend adding a class to each clickable slide such as "slide".
Then querySelect them all to return an array

```
var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
// create a counter variable
counter = 0;
```

Next you will want to create an interval or a setTimeout function
Like this

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
     // code executes here 
     // check if counter is larger than the array of slides 
     // and reset it
     if(counter === slides.length){
        counter = 0;
     }
     // emulate click event on slide
     slides[counter].click();
     counter++;// increase counter so it can click another slide
}, 1000);// 1000 being 1 second delay or interval
```

to disable the interval (clearing it completely) use

```
clearInterval(interval);// takes an interval created as a parameter
```

Comment: I want to keep the `click` event as is.

Comment: Click event as in the code that is in your jquery click function? Edit - run the code in your fiddle that I provided u with, and swap out ".slides" with ".slidelink"

Comment: No, code executes just handles clicking the each slide and any custom code u want to call, leave ur click listener in JQuery.

Word of advice  
`// simulates as if user clicked and element
slides[counter].click();`

Is totally different from 
`// adds event listener click, from jquery
$(".slidelink").click()`



Leaving it as is it will work fine

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c0stmbqg/6/ Thanks it is working but when I click on one, it should pick up from the next one but instead it is just starting from where it left off.

Comment: Give each "slidelink" an attribute of "data-position" call "position" what u like and assign it numbers 0 then 1 then 2 in that order so the first slidelink should have a data-position="0", the second one data-position="1"... in your jquery click listener grab the attribute value of data-position from the clicked element into a variable

`var position = $(this).attr("data-position");`

then set the counter variable to that

`counter = parseInt(position);`

Make sure your JQuery event listener is after the code i gave u